# Wordpress - remove parent's slug from URL

Tags: wordpress, url, parent-child

I'm trying to remove parent's pages slug from my URL's in Wordpress. Ie., instead of:

http://domain.com/grandparent/parent/child

I would need URL:

http://domain.com/child

Anyone knows how to do this? Thanks

Comment: Look a this:


http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6106/remove-parent-category-from-permalink-basically-only-have-the-child-category  



Feedback to us. Good luck

Comment: Thanks, this works for categories, but doesn't work for removing pages slugs though...

Answer (score -1):

You can change the links your site generates by changing your [Wordpress Permalinks](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#Choosing_your_permalink_structure) structure

From your dashboard

```
Settings > Permalinks
```

Comment: This doesn't help, have the url set to `%postname%` still shows parents.